# Stylus can't do simple math

Tags: stylus

Why isn't this working in Stylus?

```
gutter = 2%
get(numerator, denominator)
    x = (numerator / denominator) * 100% // get(1, 4) returns 25% as it should
    (x) - gutter // returns x as 24.5% wtf
```

Works fine in Sass

```
$gutter: 2%;
@function foo($numerator, $denominator) {
    $x: ($numerator / $denominator) * 100%;
    @return $x - $gutter;
}
foo {
    width: foo(1, 4); // returns 23% as it should
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add the percent at the end (`(25 - 2) * 1%` instead of `(25%)-2%`)? (25 minus 2% of 25)% is 24.5%... Don't know Stylus, though, so no idea if intentional

Answer (score 2):

Yep sure does. I suck for not noticing that. This works.

```
gutter = 2
get(numerator, denominator)
    x = (numerator / denominator) * 100 // get(1, 4) returns 25% as it should
    width ((x) - (gutter))% // returns x as 24.5% wtf
span
    display inline-block
    height 40px
    get(1, 4)
```